# Printing an array in a pattern in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops

This is my java code to print the array in this format ([Array Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rg2eG.png)):

```java
for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        System.out.print("\t");
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < (strArr.length - i); k++) {
        System.out.print(strArr[i] + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

But I get the wrong format ([Wrong pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nNCI.png)). I tried to find the error but can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add one more tab here `System.out.print("\t\t");`

```
String[] strArr = new String[]{"aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee"};
for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    System.out.print("\t\t");
  }
  for (int k = 0; k < (strArr.length - i); k++) {
    System.out.print(strArr[i] + "\t");
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

```
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
    bbb bbb bbb bbb 
        ccc ccc ccc 
            ddd ddd 
                eee
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) and formatting the `String`(s). Like,

```
String[] strArr = { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee" };
for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
    StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner("\t");
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        sj.add(String.format("%s", "   "));
    }
    for (int j = i; j < strArr.length; j++) {
        sj.add(String.format("%s", strArr[i]));
    }
    System.out.println(sj);
}
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa
    bbb bbb bbb bbb
        ccc ccc ccc
            ddd ddd
                eee
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) instead of loops. Code might look something like this:

```java
String[] arr = new String[]{"aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee"};

String tab = "    ";
String space = " ";

IntStream.range(0, arr.length).forEach(i -> {
    IntStream.range(0, i)
            .forEach(j -> System.out.print(tab));
    IntStream.range(0, arr.length - i)
            .forEach(k -> System.out.print(arr[i] + space));
    System.out.println();
});
```

Output:

```
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
    bbb bbb bbb bbb 
        ccc ccc ccc 
            ddd ddd 
                eee
```

Or another values: `String tab = "\t";` and `String space = "\t";`

---

<sup>See also: [How to replace a whole string with another in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65381483/14838237)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

By using [`String#repeat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)), you can do it with a single loop.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] strArr = { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee" };
        for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("\t".repeat(i) + (strArr[i] + "\t").repeat(strArr.length - i - 1) + strArr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa
    bbb bbb bbb bbb
        ccc ccc ccc
            ddd ddd
                eee
```