# How to replace a whole string with another in an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, replace

I want to replace, say String `oldString` with String `newString` in an Array along the lines of:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i].equals(oldString)) {
        text[i] = text[i].replace(oldString, newString);
    }
}
```

How would one go about this in Java?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java replace certain string in array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005284/java-replace-certain-string-in-array-of-strings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `replace()` in this case, since you are already checking that `text[i]` is equal to `oldString`, which means you are replacing the entire `String`, which means assignment is sufficient:

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
   if (text[i].equals(oldString)) {
      text[i] = newString;
   }
}
```

If, on the other hand, you wanted to replace a sub-string of `text[i]` which is equal to `oldString` to `newString`, you could write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    text[i] = text[i].replace(oldString,newString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) over the indices of this array and process certain strings in a certain way:

```java
String[] text = {"Lorem", "oldString", "dolor", "sit", "amet"};

IntStream.range(0, text.length)
        // to filter the certain strings, or you
        // can skip this line to process each string
        .filter(i -> text[i].equals("oldString"))
        // processing a string
        .forEach(i -> text[i] = text[i].replace("oldString", "newString"));

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(text));
// [Lorem, newString, dolor, sit, amet]
```

---

<sup>See also: [Replace certain string in array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65381569/14838237)</sup>